# Azure Rest API configuration details

Tags: azure

Cloud Connection getting error on Azure, Rest API & Callback API Configuration trying to make but not connecting on it giveing error

Comment: What API are you trying to call? How're you making the REST call? Please elaborate the error/error code and include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a couple ways to call REST APIs in Azure. There is a neat video that explains how to do this via Postman [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh37VQ3_exk). Also ensure that the access token being used for Authentication is a valid one in the Authorization header. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) doc to understand the right format.

Comment: Thanks I got it, Its working with Postman

Comment: @Gagan Glad to know. Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful. :)